# Doing calculations between with values from an array in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Okay, so I have an array that looks something like the following:

```
[
  { "initStamp": 745679566,"compStamp":  840373966 }, 
  { "initStamp": 745671000,"compStamp":  840375000 }, ....
]
```

I'm trying to do some arithmetic using JavaScript and then return the total.

So basically, I'm thinking something like the following,

```
    const count = 0;
    const calc = data.map((itm, idx) => {
        const created = itm.initStamp;
        const comp = itm.compStamp;
        var hours = Math.abs(comp - created) / 3.6e6;
        var count = count + hours;
        return count
    });
```

But I quickly realised Javascript is not Python.

What would be the most correct Javascript way of performing something like this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is "*most correct*" to you? This reads a lot like an opinion-based question, which is off-topic per the [help/on-topic]. Why doesn't the code you've already written meet your requirements, exactly?

Comment: You are correct that JS is not Python. Why is the function `async` here? It's not clear what the issue is. "Most correct" is more of an opinion than anything else, a simple for-loop, `forEach`, `reduce`, all would work. `map` makes no sense since you don't care about a value for each element--you're reducing the collection to a single value.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in a simple for loop?

```
let count = 0; 
for (let i = 0; i<array.length; i++){
   count += Math.abs(array[i].compStamp - array[i].initStamp) / 3.6e6;
}
return count;
```